# How to iterate through only Rows in the AutoFiltered Worksheet in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Need to iterate through only the rows (intention is to get the Row Index) in a AutoFiltered Range?

I tried this blk:

```
For Each ele In rng 
    RowInd = ele.Rows.Address
    RowNum = Split(RowInd, "$")(2)
Next ele
```

This iterates in all the Cells in the rng. But I don't need this. I need to iterate through any one cell (say any cell in Column 2 or 1) in each row in that range.

Comment: Do you want to lopop the Filterd Range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with an tempRng.

First you have to do this like Mirg said and give the tempRng the Column you want to loop.

And the loop you should do like this.

```
For Each ele In tempRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

so you will ony Loop the Filterd Range.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim tempRng As Range

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D11")
Set tempRng = Rng.Columns(1)

    For Each ele In tempRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        RowInd = ele.Rows.Address
        RowNum = Split(RowInd, "$")(2)
    Next ele
```

Comment: That just worked like a CHARM! Thanks Moosil and Mrig! \m/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
For Each ele In rng
```

use

```
For Each ele In rng.Columns(1).Cells
```

This will loop through **Column 1** (first column) of the range. If your range is `"C1:G10"` then `rng.Columns(1).Cells` will loop through `Column C`, `rng.Columns(2).Cells` will loop through `Column D`, and so on.

Change `1` to column number needed.