# Stepping through Filtered range vs checking every row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of about 2700 items.  The status of those items items are normally either Active, Obsolete or History.  The number of Active numbers is around 700.  I want to go through the list and compare it to the previous list to see if any of the Active items are new.  My plan is to see if the first column number exists in the previous list, and if so, if it "Impl. Date" is the same.

I have an idea to simply check every item in the new list to see if its Status is active, if so do the check, if not go to the next row and check the next item in a big for loop.  It should work as its a straight forward approach, but you winding up checking 2000 rows that could have been skipped.

I was wondering if through VBA if it would be better to apply a filter to the data first so that only the Active numbers are showing, then somehow only step through the visible rows?  I can't see my for `x=1 to lastrow` approach working here as the row numbers will be increment by random amounts.

#### Sample Data

```
ABCD    Title                           Manual  DDDD    Issue Date    Impl. Date      Status
0001    GC of C, August 1990                            Aug 1, 1990   Aug 1, 1990     Obsolete
0002    Supp GC of C, April 1992                        Apr 1, 1992   Sep 1, 1992     Obsolete
0100    GC of C                                         Nov 30, 2016  Jan 12, 2017    Active
0100    GC of C                                         Apr 1, 2005   Sep 20, 2007    History
0100    GC of C                                         Apr 30, 2010  May 20, 2010    History
0102    W of M                                          Oct 1, 1992   Mar 17, 1994    Active
```

## What I have tried so far

Still in the thinking stage on this one and did not know if the Filtered approach was even viable.  I can see how to filter the list in VBA,  just not sure how to step through the rows (get the row numbers) to turn around and do my check against the existing sheet.

This is my work in progress for a line by line check

```
    'Open existing workbook
    Set Existing = Workbooks.Open(Dir(ExistingDir & "\*list.xml"), ReadOnly:=True)

    'Find target columns
    ImpCol = Source.Sheet1.Rows("3:3").Find(What:="Status", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    StatusCol = Source.Sheet1.Rows("3:3").Find(What:="Status", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    'Find last used row of column A
    LastRow = Source.Sheet1.Range("A" & Source.Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Counter_X = 4 To LastRow

    Select Case Source.Sheet1.Cells(Counter_X, StatusCol.Column)

        Case "Active"
            'Check is item does not exists in existing list as active with same Impl.Date and active status
            If Not (Existing.Sheet1.Cells(Existing.Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Source.Sheet1.Cells(Counter_X, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Row, StatusCol.Column).Value = "Active" _
                And _
               Existing.Sheet1.Cells(Existing.Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Source.Sheet1.Cells(Counter_X, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Row, ImpCol.Column).Value = Source.Sheet1.Cells(Counter_X, ImpCol.Column)) _
                Then
            'If so do NewActive Routine'
            Else
            'do nothing
            End If
```

Comment: Typically you'd loop over a filtered range using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypevisible)`  Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343278/how-to-iterate-through-only-rows-in-the-autofiltered-worksheet-in-excel-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams  Something along the lines of: `For X = 3 to lastrow / IF SpecialCells(xlcelltypevisible)= true then... / Next X`

Comment: @TimWilliams Nice find on that link.  My google foo did not turn that up for me.  Is stepping  through the better approach as I am thinking?

Comment: No not a `For X ... Next X` loop - see the accepted answer at the link I posted.  You'd use a `For Each` loop over the return value from SpecialCells.  Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021876/vba-need-to-loop-through-only-visible-cells

Comment: @TimWilliams Just looked at those two answers.  when you do a for each ele in range("A2:D6"), what is an ele?  I believe last time I tried this it told me ele has to be a variant.  In this case is ele a cell, row, column?

Comment: NVM I see in the first link now that it was restricted to a single column, so whether is be a row or a cell it does not matter.

Comment: You could collect all of the old list entries into a collection using a unique key for each and then loop all of the active items in the new list and look for that unique identifier in the collection, If it isn't there, add that to a different collection to house new entries. You then have a collection of anything new.

Comment: Thank you for the alternate approach @SmileyFtW

Comment: Which column holds your unique values? If not too many unique values you can pull the old list into an array in one go, use that as criteria on AutoFilter on the new one. Then filter the other column to be Active. If I'm not mistakeb, that would leave you with new Active cells

Comment: Hm maybe scratch that comment since you want to check dates too (just re-read that part )

Comment: @JvdV its a combination of cells that create the uniqueness.  hope I am going to explain this right.  When the new list comes out, an item number will either keep its status, have its status changed to obsolete if its not replaced, or changed to history is a new version of the item comes out.  Iin the new list the new row for the number would appear with all the same information as the previous list with the exception of IMP DATE.

Comment: My ultimate goal when I get to the end of this chunk of code is to develop a list of missing new files.  If no files are missing, then move certain files to a dated archive folder, provide a hyperlink in the new list to the archive folder for the History verrsion or obsolete version, and upload all the new files in the their approriate directories, and create their corresponding links.  But all that is not part of this question.  I am just working on how to flag new content at the moment.  one step at a time!

Comment: Then I'd go with something along the line of going through visible cells after applying a filter to the new list, then either work with collection/dictionary or since your dataset is rather small, you could go with WorksheetFunction.CountIfs maybe. See which would be fastest.

Comment: @JvdV I was so focused on .find, I had not considered using countifs.  Thanks for the idea